# Problem getting edited cell value using cell editing events in jqGrid

Tags: jqgrid

I've just started using jqGrid and am having a problem trying to get the value of an edited cell when it loses focus. I have a two-column grid with only the first column editable. Eventually my aim is that when the user clicks out of a cell in this column, it will make an Ajax call to the server to populate the second column with a value. Right now, I'm testing by just having the value of the cell displayed in a div on the page. I find the event model very unclear and have tried all the events related to cell editing (beforeEditCell, afterEditCell, beforeSubmitCell, onSubmitCell, etc.) Only the beforeSubmitCell and onSubmitCell events actually return the value. The problem in my test is that when I first edit a cell, the correct value is shown, but when I edit other cells it keeps showing the value and row ID from the first edited cell. Here is my test page: http://www.galcott.com/jqgrid.html where you can see this happening and look at the code.

Comment: From where you read about the cell events in jqGrid?

Comment: Aren't you the developer? That's a strange question to ask. I read about them here. https://www.guriddo.net/documentation/guriddo/javascript/user-guide/editing/

Comment: It is not strange, since the events described into the docs should return some value - in your case true or false. In you case the event does not return value, which mean false -i.e the input stay open as you described.

Comment: I don't understand what you're saying. Did you actually try the page? The problem is that it seems to be constantly returning the same value for the row index and the cell content.

Answer (score 0):

You have a lot of errors in your code and setup, which causes unexpected behavior.

1.You do not have included one of the important file - the language file. If you have include it you will see where is the problem.

2.You do not have include css framework file, which will cause sometime unexpected behavior.

3.You save a error in the grid parameter cellsubmit - in your code it is *cellSubmit*, while the working option is **cellsubmit** - JavaScript is case sensitive

4.At last the event **onSubmitCell** as I say in my comment should return true or false i.e

```
onSubmitCell: function(rowid, cellname, value, iRow, iCol) {
    $('#celldata').html(iRow + '  ' + value); 
    if(some condition) { 
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

In your code do:

```
$("#tbl1").jqGrid({
    width: 400, 
    height: 400, 
    cellsubmit: 'clientArray', 
    editurl: 'clientArray', 
...
```

and it will work

Comment: Just changing cellSubmit to cellsubmit fixed the problem. I did notice that you aren't consistent in the way properties are capitalized - for example, why does 'cellEdit' use a capital and 'cellsubmit' doesn't?

I did include the CSS so I don't know what you mean about that. And I wasn't aware of any language file but it doesn't seem to be necessary.

Comment: The necessary and sufficient condition to know the product is not only to know the documentation url, but to read them [Install](http://www.guriddo.net/documentation/guriddo/javascript/#using-jquery-ui-css-framework)